# opening a file with admin priviliges in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, privileges

There is a file `context.xml` in the path :

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\conf\context.xml
```

I have to edit this file. But i am unable to do so.When i try to save the edits *(ctrl+s)* , I get a message `Access Denied` . How can i open these type of files with admin privilege ?

To run any type of software that needs admin privilege,i just click run as administrator. What do i do in this case ?

*NOTE : I am the admin on my computer*

*NOTE : Answer me in context to Windows 7*

Comment: Are you sure it's not read only (look in properties)? Also, who has ownership of the file?

Comment: I don't know how to do this. But what I do is open the editor as administrator.

Comment: @criziot this is it !

Comment: As it works for you I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a file for editing in Administrator mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/219179/how-to-open-a-file-for-editing-in-administrator-mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to do that directly. But, as a workaround, you can open you editor with admin priviledges (with run as administrator) and then open the file you want to edit from the editor.

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way. You can not start an application associated with a file with admin permissions directly.

Comment: @Robert I also think that's true. But as I'm not a Windows user I couldn't say it for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click on the file you want to open and then press Run as Admin

Comment: i don't see `run as admin` option

Comment: This works if you right click an executable (EXE) file. But does not work if you right click a data file like .TXT which you want to be opened by its associated program.